# Convert date formatted as numeric without leading 0 for months < 10 to date format t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, format

Have a date field that I need to convert from mddyy or mmddyy (numeric format) when the month is >=10 to a mmddyy date format.  Have yet to find any answers on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):-

```
FORMAT ( table.myDateColumn, 'd', 'en-US' )
```

Edit:-

Try this:-

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(MONTH(DateColumn)))+'/'+LTRIM(STR(DAY(DateColumn)))+'/'+STR(YEAR(DateColumn),4)
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, but in MSMS 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Microsoft Management Studio. Thanks!  And I'm sorry, obviously I meant to say <=10 in my original post.

Comment: Thank you very much again.  In my sample date which reads 40113, the output from the above is 10/29/2009 when it should be 04/01/2013.  Thank you. This is proving to be challenging!

Comment: You want to convert from mddyy or mmddyy or mddyy or mmddyyyy??

Comment: I want to convert mddyy (when month is < 10) or mmddyy (when month is >=10) to mmddyyyy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This gets it in the genearal appearance I sought:

```
select
CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(varchar(6), datefield)) < 6
THEN ('0' + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), datefield),1) + '-' +
      SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), datefield),2,2) + '-' +
      LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(7), datefield),4))
ELSE (LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), datefield),2) + '-' +
      SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), datefield),3,2) + '-' +
     LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(7), datefield),4))
END as DesiredDate
```

Comment: To get the above in datetime format, simply insert convert (datetime before Case and close the case by putting an ending ) after End, and that will put the above in datetime forma.

Answer (score 0):

My above solution technically does not work nor is consistent with SQL's system-wide setting in SQL Server - the "two-digit year cutoff".  Typically SQL Server considers any date with a 2 digit year or value of 49 as 20xx year or 2049.  Dates with a 2 digit year after that, say 70 get interpreted as 19xx (70 -> 1970).  Thanks to marc_s for his post on the topic.  My solution does not require a custom function or SQL Server setting change, and it does account for both one and two digit months.  It is:

```
Select
Convert (datetime, --varchar depending on desired format--
         CASE 
    WHEN         LEN(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield))     <  6 and
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),4,2) <  50
    THEN ('0' + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),1))  + '-' +
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2,2) + '-' +
         ('20'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2))
    WHEN         LEN(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield))     =  6 and
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),5,2) <  50
    THEN          (LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2))  + '-' +
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2,2) + '-' +
         ('20'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2))
    WHEN         LEN(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield))     <  6 and
      SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),4,2) >= 50
    THEN ('0' + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),1))  + '-' +
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),5,2) + '-' +
         ('19'+RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2)) 
    WHEN         LEN(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield))     =  6 and
           SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),5,2) >= 50
    THEN       (LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2))  + '-' +
                SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(6), dt.datefield),2,2) + '-' +
    ('19'+(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(7), dt.datefield),2)))
    End) as MaintDate 
FROM   
dbo.date_table dt
```